# Change ArcGIS server port number

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-server

ArcGIS Server connects its internet services with port 6080 and uses a site name of arcgis. For example, the default URL to an ArcGIS Server site is http://gisserver.domain.com:6080/arcgis. I want to get rid of the port number? any way to get rid of this port number?

Comment: Just use some proxy on standard 80/443 http/https ports, i.e. nginx, haproxy and all the way

Answer (score 0):

https://stateparkmap.okstate.edu/ArcGISServer/ArcGISServer/SetupFiles/Documentation/install_guides/Server/01nm00000025000000.htm

hey dude
if you want to change the ports inside service use this help page,

"Using a different set of port numbers
If you want ArcGIS Server to use a different set of port numbers, log in to the Administrator Directory and click machines >  > edit. In the list of ports, type the new port numbers you want to use and click Save Edits. You can do this on each GIS server participating in the site if desired."

Comment: also change ports in this file in the same way : C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\framework\runtime\tomcat\conf\server.xml and restart services